# Windows 7 Windows Explorer can't see iPhone 5S any more

Tags: iphone, usb, windows

I used to be able to access my iPhone directly from Windows Explorer under Windows 7, can't now. iTunes can see the phone, Windows 7 Explorer can't.

Is there any known fix?

Comment: Are you using Windows to copy photos? Like when it shows up as a USB drive?

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes. That has always worked fine. I don't want to get into some iTunes hell with "syncing" and having it copy things back to the phone that I don't want to go there.

Comment: @IronCraftMan iTunes appears to say it does not support importing photos from the iPhone to Windows. It says you do that using Windows or Photoshop. All iTunes admits it can do is copy pictures TO the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check device manager to see if the iphone is listed, or if you have anything with a question or exclamation mark.

Edit- also check disk management (just type diskmgmt.msc on start menu and press enter, or into windows + R run box and press enter) to see if the drive is possibly detected without a letter assigned.

Comment: I should also say, if you find anything showing up with issues in device manager, try deleting the driver for that device and letting it reinstall.

Comment: Yeah, there's an "MTP USB Device": "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)"

Comment: Nothing in Disk Management

Comment: Uninstalled MTP USB Device, unplugged it, let it plug-n-play, and now it's back. FIrstborn to be named Jeff, thx.

Comment: Glad to hear this helped, thx for confirming!